# Search results with pagination code won't return results

Tags: php, pdo

I'm having a hard time getting this search results with pagination code to work. It does successfully grab the search keyword entered in the html form on another page and brings it into this search.php page. if I echo $search I see the keyword on the page. But I get no results even though I should for the query. Can anyone see what might be going on?

```
require "PDO_Pagination.php";

if(isset($_REQUEST["search_text"]) && $_REQUEST["search_text"] != "")
{

    $search = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["search_text"]);
    $pagination->param = "&search=$search";
    echo $search;

    $pagination->rowCount("SELECT * FROM stories WHERE stories.genre = $search");
    $pagination->config(3, 5);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM stories WHERE stories.genre = $search ORDER BY SID ASC LIMIT $pagination->start_row, $pagination->max_rows";
    $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $model = array();

    while($rows = $query->fetch())
    {
        $model[] = $rows;
    }
}
else
{
    $pagination->rowCount("SELECT * FROM stories");
    $pagination->config(3, 5);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM stories ORDER BY SID ASC LIMIT $pagination->start_row, $pagination->max_rows";
    $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $model = array();

    while($rows = $query->fetch())
    {
        $model[] = $rows;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe something with `WHERE stories.genre = $search");` Specifically the `=`? Usually you would need a `LIKE`.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try. Yeah, I did originally have it as = '%$search%' but that wasn't working either. No results. I only recently tried changing it to = $search. Either way, that's not it...

Comment: My point was I used like first and it didn't work. But JC Sama's answer below is getting the results to come through it looksl ike

Comment: I see. In your comment you said *= %$search%* not *LIKE %$search%*. That is why I reiterated it. But if its working, then great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM stories";

if(isset($_REQUEST["search_text"]) && $_REQUEST["search_text"] != "")
{
    $search = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["search_text"]);
    $pagination->param = "&search=$search";
    $query .= " WHERE genre LIKE '%$search%'";
}
// No need for else statement.
$pagination->rowCount($query);
$pagination->config(3, 5);
$query .= " ORDER BY SID ASC LIMIT {$pagination->start_row}, {$pagination->max_rows}";

$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$model = $stmt->fetchAll();
var_dump($model);
```

Comment: Interesting. Was it just the else that was messing it up? That gets the result in a var_dump, although it won't show on the page. Maybe because it seems to duplicate the result for each vaiable in the array. Var_dump looks like this:   array(1) { [0]=> array(20) { ..other variables... ["genre"]=> string(7) "Drama" [4]=> string(7) "Drama".  So maybe I just need to figure out how to access the data and echo it now...

Comment: I got it: $model[0]['genre'] to echo value

Comment: You can remove the `while` loop and just use `fetchAll` instead

Answer (score 0):

In your query do:

```
WHERE stories.genre LIKE '%string%');
```

instead of:

```
WHERE stories.genre = 'string');
```

Because the equals will want to literally equal the field.